# How can I remove input border in React-Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I can't get rid of the [input borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpftw.png) of the Form.Control component in React-Bootstrap. I know the question has been asked and answered multiple times but the answers haven't solved my issue.

I've tried redefining the .css classes "input" and "form-control", setting their border to 0 and to none, but it didn't work. I also tried setting the outline to none, and even setting the border the same color as the current background (white) and it didn't work either. I don't know what to try anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can override React Bootstrap classes using an id on the parent node, for example:

```
<div id="parent-wrapper">
<input placeholder="something">
</div>
```

And you can redefine properties on css like this:

```
#parent-wrapper input{
border:0;
.
.
}
```